# How SciTE IDE for lua automatically or manually format my code

Tags: lua, ide, editor

I am new in lua,need basic type of help.After install **BabeLua** extension on Visual Studio,they indent and everything for me. Want to work with **SciTE** IDE,  It's a pain in having to indent my code all the time so looking a way  which can format my lua code manually and automatically.

**Note:** try to use [source-code-formatter](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SourceCodeFormatter) and [beautifier](http://web.archive.org/web/20120830041232/http://www.userpixel.com/486).I failed to use them in my lua module.How to use them in lua?They are workable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea with those beautifiers you reference is that you can run them as an external program: save your current buffer to a file, run through the filter to beautify, then read the result back into the current buffer in SciTE.

I can vouch for the second program as I used it in the past to re-indent some of my code; I ended up [re-implementing it in Perl](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/lua-beautifier-in-55-lines-of-perl) as it didn't handle all the cases I was interested in.

If you want to integrate it into SciTE, you can probably strip some of the io functions and just use functions to read buffer content in SciTE (like `GetLine`) and then modify the indentation (probably using `GetLineIndentation` and `SetLineIndentation`). I've implemented a very similar logic in [my Lua IDE](https://studio.zerobrane.com/), which is using the same editor component that is used in SciTE.